# Intellisense autocomplete does not work well in VS Code for JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, module, visual-studio-code, jsdoc

Created simple bot app with node js (code mentioned below). Auto-complete works fine in line 22 for `session` parameter. However does not work in line 29 for `session` parameter (in `ReceiveMessage()` function) even with JSDoc definitions.

```
var restify = require('restify');
var builder = require('botbuilder');

// Setup Restify Server
var server = restify.createServer();
server.listen(process.env.port || process.env.PORT || 3978, function () {
   console.log('%s listening to %s', server.name, server.url); 
});

// Create chat connector for communicating with the Bot Framework Service
var connector = new builder.ChatConnector({
    appId: process.env.MICROSOFT_APP_ID,
    appPassword: process.env.MICROSOFT_APP_PASSWORD
});

// Listen for messages from users 
server.post('/api/messages', connector.listen());

// Receive messages from the user and respond by echoing each message back (prefixed with 'You said:')
var dialog = require("./rootdialog")
var bot = new builder.UniversalBot(connector, function (session) {
    session.send("You said: %s", session.message.text);
});

/**
 * @param {Session} {session}
 */
function ReceiveMessage(/*Session*/session) {
    session.send("You said: %s", session.message.text);    
}
```

**VS Code for Node.js Development Quickstart Pack** extension installed, does not work without it as well. Also reproduced without extensions.

Type Session defined in `botbuilder`:

```
npm install --save botbuilder
npm install --save restify
```

in file: `node_modules/botbuilder/lib/botbuilder.d.ts`

Is it [VS Code bug](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/31233) or there is a way to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution mentioned on [GitHub](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/31233#issuecomment-317597227):

> Looks like [Microsoft/TypeScript#11825](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/11825)
>
> These patterns should work:

```
import * as builder from 'botbuilder';

/**
 * @param {builder.Session} session
 */
function ReceiveMessage(session) {
    session.send("You said: %s", session.message.text);    
}
```

> or

```
const {Session} = require('botbuilder');

/**
 * @param {Session} session
 */
function ReceiveMessage(session) {
    session.send("You said: %s", session.message.text);    
}
```

This works!

Comment: First option worked like a champ.  Any danger to it?

// const builder = new require("botbuilder");

import * as builder from 'botbuilder';

// const restify = new require("restify");

import * as restify from 'restify';